# Resource mange external nodes in Jenkins for tests

Tags: resources, jenkins, external, nodes, jenkins-plugins

My problem is that I have code that need a rebooted node.  I have many long running Jenkins test jobs that needs to be executed on rebooted nodes.

My existing solution is to define multiple "proxy" machines in Jenkins with the same label (TestLable) and 1 executor per machine. I bind all the test jobs to the label (TestLable). In the test execution script I detect the Jenkins machine (Jenkins env. NODE_NAME) and use that to know what physical physical machine the tests should use.

Do anybody know of a better solution?

The above works but I need to define a high number of “nodes/machines” that may not be needed. What I would like was a plugin that would be able to grant a token to a Jenkins job. This way a job would not be executed before a Jenkins executor and a token was free.  The token should be a string so that my test jobs could use it to know what external node it could use.

Comment: Why not have different jobs for the tests that should be run in parallel?

Comment: Hmmm.  The test jobs are already devided in to the smallest size possible Jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 0):

We have written our own scheduler that allocates stuff before starting Jenkins nodes. There may be a better solution - but this works for us mostly. I've yet to come across an off-the-shelf scheduler that can deal with complicated allocation of different hardware resources. We have n box types, allocated to n build types.

Some build types we have are not compatible together without destroying all persistent data - which may be required as it takes a long time to gather. Some jobs require combinations of these hardware types. We store the details in a DB, and then use business logic to determine how it is allocated. We've often found that particular job types need additional business logic or extra data fields to account for their specific requirements.

So it may be the best way is to write your own scheduler, in your own language of choice, which takes into account your particular needs.